# Azure Wordpress login credentials when making new website

Tags: azure, authentication, wordpress

I just created a new website from the azure website creation wizard. I clicked "new website" followed by "from gallery" and it creates a nice brand new wordpress install on an azure subdomain. the link the site is click-able, and I am at the standard wordpress login page.

However, I am not sure what the username or password is. typical WP installs give you an area to add the new username and new password for the fresh install. this wizard just spits out a new site, however, I need to find out how to login.

Specifically, where do I find my login credentials to the actual WP site?

Answer (score 0):

The username is admin. You should have been required to enter a password during the setup. See http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-from-gallery/ for a full step by step.